How can I get a list of projects that one project depends on via `nx`?
I am using nx to manage a mono repo which includes a few hundreds projects. I am looking for a way to find one project's dependencies. For example, I have below structure:
apps/project-1
apps/project-2
apps/project-base

project-1 depends on project2 and project-base. How can I list them for project-1 via nx command line?
I know I can use nx graph --focus project-1, but it open a web UI to show the dependency tree. How can I let the command return a string which includes project-2 and project-bas?
